# Embed HTML UI Shiny application in package

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to include a shiny implementation in a package I'm making. I see that in `shiny::runApp()` you can specify the UI and server as a list rather than a directory location:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
  }
))
```

How do you do this when using a custom [HTML UI](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#html-ui)? And where should the relevant files be placed in a package's directory? The layout of the shiny application would look something like this:

```
server.R
www/
    style.css
    scripts.js
```

I think the solution might involve `includeHTML()`, `includeCSS()` etc., but I can't figure out what the documentation is saying.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use runApp in the above list() style with an HTML file for ui? Can't you just make a index.html in the www folder and then just runApp(yourfolder)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You package hierarchy should look like this :

```
R
  launcher.R
man 
inst
   myshinyapp
        server.R
        www
           index.html      ## here your ui interface
           shared
                 js
                    yourscript.js
                 css
                    style.css
```

in launcher.R should add this function:

```
runUI <- function ()
    shiny::runApp(
        system.file('myshinyapp',                                                    
         package='my_package_name')) ## your package name here
```

You should export/import in NAMESPACE:

```
export(runUI)
import(shiny)
```

and in DESCRIPTION imports sections:

```
Imports:shiny
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can achieve this by putting all your HTML inside the HTML() function. Make sure you pass valid HTML for Shiny then you should be fine!

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    HTML("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your index.html containing your HTML into the www folder. Now **remove** ui.R if it exists. Now simply

```
runApp(yourFolder)
```

where yourFolder should be the path to your server.R. If your index.html is correctly set up then the Shiny App should run.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is not what I'm looking for though. I know you can use `runApp()` to specify a folder location, but I want to specify the server and UI in a list format similar to my example above. This is because I'm embedding the shiny application in a package. I would rather not mess around with paths on the user's computer. At the moment it looks like I'll probably have to use `runApp()` and point to the user's `.Library`. Not the worst solution but it would be nicer to be able to do it like you can with the UI.r format.